# Extract all links from a page in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am looking to extract all links from webpages. The process I had previously been using was to extract the "href" option eg.:

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "lxml")
 for a in soup.findAll("a"):
     print (a["href"])
```

Some links however have `onclick` attribute instead of using `href`

e.g.:

```
   <a href="#" onclick="window.open('link_to_open_was_here', '', 'height=400,width=600'); return false;" title="..." style="..." target="_blank">...</span></a>
```

and other links in the menu bars are constructed with javascript' window.open options.

I could probably write code that identifies the ways that are not with the href attribute, but is there an easier/more standard way extract out all links from a html page?

**Followup:**

I am specifically interested in ways to extract links which are not part of standard "href" attribute in the "a" tag, which can easily be extracted (e.g. i want to extract links which are included via window.open() or javascript... or other ways in which links are included on a page). Relatedly, since most links on sites are relative, looking for text on the page that start with http, is not going to capture them all.

Comment: Sorry, i misread the question. Bs4 is not designed to parse js, so i don't think there is an easy way to get results. As a 'hacky' solution you could use regex for links with an 'onclick' attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of grabbing everything is just to convert the entire soup results into a string and grab everything with `http` using regex:

```
soup = str(soup)

links = re.findall(r'(http.*?)"', soup)
```

Comment: That solutions risks to miss relative links and to include some unwanted links to js or css files for instance.
Restricting to <a> content would probably already exlude the second drawback.

Comment: Perhaps, but there are no "unwanted" links in this case because the problem is to extract "all" links from a page, at least as the question is currently formulated.